# SQLi runs the wrong query

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have made a website that is vulnerable against `SQLi`.
But when I run a GET Request with the `SQLi` `'--` I get the wrong query output. Can someone help me with this?

This is my SQLi

[image]

This is how SQL runs the query.

[image]

The SQL query suppose to be different. It should have been: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE id LIKE '%'` which should output all the data from the `product` table.

Code snippet

[image]

Comment: what does `$_GET['test']` return?

Comment: $_GET['test'] echo's :   '--

Comment: why would you even make a website that is sql-injectable?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct and it's doing exactly what you told it to, given the input.

The GET request value is `'--` and that is substituted for the variable `$test` in your SQL query string. But it doesn't remove what comes *after* the `$test` variable in the SQL query string.

Let me use some color-coding to show you:

> SELECT * FROM product WHERE id LIKE '%`$test`%'
>
> SELECT * FROM product WHERE id LIKE '%`'--`%'

The characters `--` form the start of an SQL comment, so anything after that is ignored after your SQL injection happens. The only functional part of the query is:

> SELECT * FROM product WHERE id LIKE '%'